# Multi column autocomplete for ASP.Net, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I found a library where I could use multicolumn autocomplete for a Web Forms project. Is there a way to do this in MVC?
So I start typing in a surname and I see a list underneath showing the surnames with the letters typed in so far, followed by the forename and the employee number. When I select one, the textbox is populated by the employee number. For example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this from a JQuery/Ajax perspective and it should be pretty simple.  You an have an action that returns JSON.  Focus your googling on Ajax and not MVC specific and just have your JSon result either return the formatted item or concatenate with Javascript before adding the item.